# AutoValue - public constructor possible

Tags: java, auto-value

Is this possible? Or is the only solution the builder? Having a class with 10 fields would mean have to duplicate the 10 fields in the builder so that `AutoValue` works. Or via a manual written create function? Or am I missing something?

I just want to create an object of my `AutoValue` class outside of the package...

Here's a short example:

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Data
{
    // Can something like this be auto generated????
    public static Data create(String field1, String field2, ...)
    {
        return new AutoValue_Data(field1, field2, ...);
    }

    public abstract String field1();
    public abstract String field2();
    ...

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public abstract static class Builder {
        // Or can I tell the builder to create setters for ALL fields 
        // automatically instead of having to declare them one by one?
        public abstract Builder setField1(String field1);
        public abstract Builder setField2(String field2);
        ...
        public abstract Data build();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use the builder pattern, you may use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

The `create()` method is just a wrapper around the constructor to hide implementation details like the class `AutoValue_Data` itself. If you just don't want to write everything yourself, you can find a [plugin for Android Studio](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/8091-autovalue-plugin) for creating these methods automatically.